# Still cannot start the Mongodb on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mongodb

I installed the Mongodb following [this tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), but it cannot be started.
I have tried all methods on this site related to my problem:

1) remove the lock file.
2) create the db directory as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149693/3552975).
3) comment the ip following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532276/3552975)
4) find this by follwing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28247278/3552975):

```
lerner    2562  1689  0 20:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongod
```

5) stop, start and restart, the status is always stop/waiting
and many others, most of which are very outdated.

When I run mongo it reads that:

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.2 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   2018-09-18T20:59:33.052+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
>   to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
>   Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused
>   : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13 @(connect):1:6 exception:
>   connect failed

I have successfully installed it on three machines, two 16.04 and one 18.04, and all function well, then I think this problem is particular to 14.04.

Could anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I cannot install mongodb 4.02 on Ubuntu 14.04. It became all ok once I removed the mongodb 4.02 and installed the 3.00.